# Interfaz que implementa otra interfaz

Tags: php, poo, herencia

¿Como podemos crear una interfaz compuesta de otras interfaces?

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

namespace Domain\Interfaces;

interface Arrayable
{
    public function toArray();
}

interface Jsonable
{
    public function toJson();
}

interface Manager implements Arrayable, Jsonable
{
    // void
}
```

El uso de `implements` genera un error:

`syntax error, unexpected 'implements' (T_IMPLEMENTS), expecting '{'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder hacer interfaces compuestas de otras interfaces en lugar de utilizar `implements` debemos utilizar `extends`. Las interfaces no implementan nada pero si pueden extender de otras interfaces. Adesmás a diferencia de la herencia de de clases las interfaces en php si permiten herencia múltiple.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

namespace Domain\Interfaces;

interface Arrayable
{
    public function toArray();
}

interface Jsonable
{
    public function toJson();
}

interface Manager extends Arrayable, Jsonable
{
    // void
}
```

Otra alternativa puede ser crear una clase Abstacta que implemente ambas interfaces:

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

interface Arrayable
{
    public function toArray();
}

interface Jsonable
{
    public function toJson();
}

abstract class Manager implements Arrayable, Jsonable
{
    // void
}
```

Documentación:

- [Interfaces](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.interfaces)
- [Herencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.inheritance.php)
- [Abstracción de clases](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.abstract.php)